# How can i create a 3D surface Plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I need to plot 3 -D plots in MATLAB. Here is one example;

```
x=0:1:10 
for y=1:1:100
Z=1-(1-qfunc(sqrt(2*10.^(x/10)))).^y
end
```

I need to plot x y and Z in three axes, where Z is function of x and y.

How can i create a surface plot of Z along the x and y axis in MATLAB?

Comment: Have you tried using `surf`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `surf` and/or `mesh` functions as follows:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(0:10,1:100);
Z=1-(1-qfunc(sqrt(2*10.^(X/10)))).^Y;
mesh(X,Y,Z)
```

where creates a mesh, and:

```
surf(X,Y,Z)
```

creates a surface. For more options check [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/creating-mesh-and-surface-plots.html).

remember that the data should be converted to a meshgrid and then you will be able to use those functions.